# How do i correctly save CheckBox states using CursorAdapter?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, android-cursoradapter

This is my CursorAdapter class.
I am getting the scrolling issues.Actually the checkboxes are loosing their states
This is my CursorAdapter class.

```
public class TaskListAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

private Context context;
private TaskCursor tc;
ArrayList<Boolean> checkbox_arr = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
public TaskListAdapter(Context c, TaskCursor tc) {

    super(c, tc, 0);
    this.context = c;
    this.tc = tc;
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    Log.d("getViewTest", "new view");
    //this.context=context;
    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View row = li.inflate(R.layout.task_list_item, null, false);
    return row;

}


    @Override
    public void bindView(View v, final Context context, Cursor c) {
        Log.d("valuecheck","bindviewcalled");
        final Task t = tc.getTask();
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.task_checkbox);
        cb.setText(t.getName());
        final long id =t.getId();
        final Context ctx = context;
        cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        if (t.getStatus()==0) {
            cb.setChecked(false);
            Log.d("valuecheck","Status value =0" );
        } else {
            cb.setChecked(true);
            Log.d("valuecheck","Status value =1" );
        }
        cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if(isChecked) {
                        t.updateStatus(1,context); // Update it in Database
                        Log.d("valuecheck","Setting " +t.getName()+ "to status 1" );

                    } else {
                        t.updateStatus(0,context);
                        Log.d("valuecheck","Setting " +t.getName()+ "to status 0" );
                    }
                }
        });

}
}
```

I have tried using saving states using an array but in vain.I have tried all the solutions but nothing worked.

Comment: just update your data model (sqlite db in your case) whenever check box's state changes

Comment: I have added comment where i am updating them in database.
t.updateStatus is changing the values in database.